# Will daily sweeped ants eventually learn their path is a dead-end?

Tags: entomology, ant, sociality, learning

An ant colony (likely Lasius niger) made its way through one of our rooms, literally.  That is, they enter by a door and leave by the other, and *vice versa*.  Some carry eggs, but in both ways, so I'm not sure whether the nest is on one side or the other.

I sweep them outdoor everyday, but each night they repopulate the path.  **Am I wasting my time or is there a chance sweeping makes them decide it's a dead-end ?**

NB : Washing the floor didn't change anything.  I also tried to barricade with somehow large amounts of essential oil of Eucalyptus citriodora, but it didn't seem to help.  Anyway although suggestions to get them leave are welcome in comments, I'm genuinely interested in knowing if the sweeping strategy may have an effect or not.

Comment: Related : https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20431/can-ants-learn-things

Comment: I often trace the trail as far as I can away from my home and plant bait poison in line with their current path. I then use vinegar to scrub their path everywhere beyond the bait trap. The ants enjoy this new closer food and usually seem unable to find their way back into my home